# Why use Actors between http server and database

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, akka-persistence

I was following an app example from RockTheJVM (Daniel Ciocîrlan): https://blog.rockthejvm.com/akka-cassandra-project/

For implementing API Rest it uses Akka Http. To access Cassandra it uses Doobie.

When a request wants to create a bank account the implementation sends a message to an akka actor, then the actor create the account in Cassandra. It is something like this:

POST Request -> Akka Http endpoints -> Actor (ask/pipe pattern) -> Doobie -> Cassandra

My question is what's the benefit or advantages of using actors? Is it because of Akka Persistence?
Why if I don't want or don't need Akka Persistence, an implementation like this:

POST Request -> Akka Http endpoints -> Doobie -> Cassandra

Is there any benefit of adding actors without using Akka Persistence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Each step in the actor-based version has a different role.

The `Akka Http endpoints` process REST(HTTP) requests and turn them into application operations (Akka messages).

The `Actor (ask/pipe pattern)` implements the application operations. This uses one or more database operations, internal state, and information from other parts of the application (other Actors).

The `Doobie` element is just responsible for implementing database operations.

With the shorter pipeline you have a single element that is mapping REST API calls directly to database accesses, which is inflexible and (trust me on this one, I have the scars) leads to poor system design.

Comment: Thank you Tim for replying, I understand what you say and of course I agree. But what I want to know (maybe I have to describe my question a little bit better) is what's the benefit of actors, imagine that instead of using actors I just add a service layer: POST -> Request -> Akka Http endpoints -> Service layer -> Doobie -> Cassandra. Is this a better solution than using actors ?

Comment: If you keep the layering then the question is why use Actors as the Service layer. Lots of reasons, but a big one is that the actor model avoids a lot of threading issues. Messages are handled synchronously so there is no need to lock Actor state as it is only ever accessed by one thread at a time. The model also allows distributed operations as state is not passed between actors, only messages. But probably not the right context for a full discussion on this.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I think your answer is what I was looking for.